# C++ Iterator with hasNext and Next

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, iterator, c++14

I am new to C++ world and I need a help. My problem is I try implement my structure hash pair array, there is key and data. In this structure I have nested structure iterator with methods hasNext and next. Because I can not see my array (this array is in parent) from nested structure I need pass it through constructor, but there is error ": cannot convert from...", problem is with pass _array in method getIterator. Code is below. Could you help me? Thanks

```
#pragma once
template<typename T, typename U, int Size, int(*HashFunction)(T)>
struct HashPairPole {

// Pair - key - data
struct Par {
    // key
    T _first;
    // data
    U _second;
    // list for collision records
    Par* _overflow;

    Par(T t, U u) {
        _first = t;
        _second = u;
        _overflow = nullptr;
    }
};


HashParovePole() {}

// Static array for save data
Par* _array[Size];

// Add record into hash table
void add(T t, U u) {
    // calculating of index     
    Par* prvek;
    int idx = HashFunction(t) % Size;

    // Element will be saved in _array[idx], if it is free, else will be
    //saved to list (->_overflow)
    prvek = new Par(t, u);

    if (_array[idx] == nullptr) {
        _array[idx] = prvek;
    }
    else {
        prvek->_overflow = _array[idx];
    }
    _array[idx] = prvek;
}

// Get data from hash tabule
U& get(T t) {
    int idx = HashFunction(t) % Size;
    Par * prvni = _array[idx];

    while (prvni->_overflow != nullptr) {
        if (prvni->_first == t) {
            return prvni->_second;
        }
        prvni = prvni->_overflow;
    }

}

U& operator[](T t) {
    return get(t);
}

U operator[](T t) const {
    const U temp = get(t);
    return temp;
}

// Iterator for walking all hash table
struct iterator {
    Par* index[Size];
    Par* pomPar;
    int temp = 0;

    iterator(Par * _array) {
        index = _array;
        pomPar = index[0];
    }

    bool hasNext()const {
        return pomPar != nullptr;
    }


    std::pair<T, U> next() {
        std::pair<T, U> data;
        if (hasNext()) {
            data.first = pomPar->_first;
            data.second = pomPar->_second;
            pomPar = pomPar->_overflow;
        }
        temp++;
        pomPar = index[temp];
        return data;
    }
};

   // Vytvori iterator
   iterator getIterator() {
       return iterator(_array);
   }

};
```

Comment: On which line do you have a compilation error? What is the text of compilation error? Please read FAQ and post MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `Par * _array != Par* index[Size]`.

Comment: Off topic but... I'm guessing `HashParovePole() {}` should really be `HashPairPole() {}`?

Comment: The `hasNext` / `next` idiom is not normally used in C++. In C++, iterators come in pairs to form ranges. A container such as yours is expected to provide  `begin` and `end` iterators to form the full range of its elements. `operator++` is (normally) used to go through the range. Of course, in practice you don't need such a container anyway; just use `std::unordered_map` to get a working hash map!

Comment: This is school project and we have interface that we must implement. So I cant choose other container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, the problem is in this line:

```
Par* _array[Size];
```

Here you declare an array of size `Size` of pointers to `Par` structures, which is probably not what you want.

Later you try to pass this array to constructor `iterator(Par * _array)`, which accepts a pointer to `Par` structure, which is impossible.

I would fix this code in the following way:

```
Par _array[Size]; // Instead of Par* _array[Size]
                  // You need an array of structures instead of array of pointers
...
Par* index; // Instead of Par* index[Size]
            // Here looks like index is a pointer to a current element
...
pomPar = index; // Instead of pomPar = index[0];
                // This is a pointer to the node, while index[0] is its value
```

Also, consider using `std::vector` instead of raw pointers. It will handle memory management issues for you.

Comment: I can not change Par* _array to Par _array, because I have to abide task from teacher. I need to implement this container with this iterator, because source code from teacher use this method, unfortunately I can not change source code what I have from school.

Comment: @JanMesarč OK, there's another option: change the declaration of `iterator` constructor to accept `Par**` and do the same changes with `index` and `pomPar`.